# entity Framework 5.0 upgrade from 4.0 now can't store entities in viewstate like previously - Error serializing value

Tags: entity-framework-5

I had a large working vb.net + .NET 4.0 + EF 4.0 applications that on some web pages would store an entity in the viewstate between postbacks. Now after upgrading to EF 5.0 I get errors about "Error serializing value" or "Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.person_D21302CBADCAFE031ECF02E7BFFCAA3F9D167D6CA8CC3962440E533F5A26AA7F' in Assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyProj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable"

What do I need to do to get my application working again?

Comment: This seems to be because of proxies. Did you use proxies before upgrading? Do you use proxies in your project - If not you could just disable proxy creation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im having the same problem, I had an ASP.NET web application that used EF 4.3, and I decided to upgrade to EF 5, and now I cant store EF Objects to viestate like before, because it always raise an error serializing values. For more information let me explain why Im doing it.
In the app when you what to update an object you select it from a list, The app loads the EF Object and fill the form, then stores this object in viewstate... when you what to save changes, the app takes the previously loaded object from viewstate and modify values then save changes... I think its better than load object to fill the form and then load object againg to save changes...any suggestion would be appreciated...
PD: Sorry for my English, I try to do my best.